# What is your stance about unsolved challenge

Tags: support

I have a puzzle that isn't successfully answered.

[You can see me in different face](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/you-can-see-me-in-different-face/25322#25322)

Can I post the answer on that?

Comment: You could wait. 5 days isn't that long.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: add hints or answer it yourself. Either is acceptable, but I would suggest adding hints for a while before answering. It's possible that someone else will figure it out with a little nudge.

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

1. Begin adding hints that asymptotically approach giving the answer away.
2. Put the answer in a community wiki post.
3. Delete the question.

Comment: Deleting the question have severe problems here.

Comment: I don't see a need for CW. Answering your own questions is encouraged on the SE network.